# Applying a Regex to an upload field in Umbraco

Tags: regex, umbraco, umbraco7

Before I report this as a bug with Umbraco 7, I wanted to reach out to Umbraco users and hopefully determine the issue.

I setup a document type with an upload field with the following Regex validation:

```
(^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w ]*.*))+\.(jpg|JPG)$)
```

[Document Type With Validation - Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfQnL.jpg)

On the content side, when I complete and submit the form for the **first time**, the validation works correctly.

- No uploaded file returns the error "Value is invalid, it does not match the correct pattern"
- A file that isn't a JPG returns the error "Value is invalid, it does not match the correct pattern"

BUT, when I return to **EDIT** something else on the content side, title, etc. The  upload field that validated fine on the initial insert, fails. It returns the error "Value is invalid, it does not match the correct pattern"

[Value is Invalid - Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8VL7.jpg)

I'm required to RE-upload the image in order for it to pass validation. Basically what I'm saying is, once the image is uploaded, the filename is no longer detected by the RegEx validation and therefore, fails.

Just to be clear, the validation works fine when the content is initially submitted, and fails when edited. So this is probably not RegEx issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Regex validation works only with text fields. Not sure why the option is there for all data types, but AFAIK it is not intended to work with anything but raw text strings.

Comment: Thanks Jannik - So outside of getting a plug-in is there a way to restrict file types for the File Upload data type?

Comment: You might be able to override something in the upload flow, but it's probably pretty complicated. It may be worth a googling though.

Comment: If you want to do this, grab the source and look for the file upload - being AngularJS you could create a clone of it as a Plugin and then edit it to your heart's content - if you're familiar with AngularJS you won't have a problem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you edit, you aren't uploading a file, so it will fail the validation, as the file upload field is empty. If you edit AND upload a a file, it should work.